# Query argument spread in GraphQL

Tags: api, graphql

I have the following schema:

```
input ResumeFilter {
  id: ID
  accountId: ID
  lang: Lang
}

extend type Query {
  resume(filter: ResumeFilter): Resume!
  resumes(filter: ResumeFilter, offset: Int, limit: Int): [Resume!]!
}
```

Now I'd like to remove the `filter` keyword from the `resume` query as it won't have anything besides that:

```
extend type Query {
  resume(id: ID, accountId: ID, lang: Lang): Resume! # !!! repeats ResumeFilter !!!
  resumes(filter: ResumeFilter, offset: Int, limit: Int): [Resume!]!
}
```

To solve DRY violation I'm trying something like this:

```
extend type Query {
  resume(...ResumeFilter): Resume!
  resumes(filter: ResumeFilter, offset: Int, limit: Int): [Resume!]!
}
```

Which is syntactically incorrect. Is there a syntax/way to solve this case gracefully? Maybe with Fragments?

Comment: As an aside, replacing a single argument that takes an input object with two or more arguments makes for a bad developer experience for anyone writing the client code as it now forces them to have use that many more variables in their document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments can only be used client-side with executable documents. There is no syntax for spreading an input object. If your server-side language supports string interpolation, you can use that. For example, in JavaScript:

```
const resumeFilterFields = `
  id: ID
  accountId: ID
  lang: Lang
`

const schema = `
  input ResumeFilter {
    ${resumeFilterFields}
  }

  extend type Query {
    resume(${resumeFilterFields}): Resume!
    resumes(filter: ResumeFilter, offset: Int, limit: Int): [Resume!]!
  }
`
```